# Create a Azure Service Bus Topic and Subscription through Logic App

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I've created a Logic App which has a HTTP Post trigger containing a JSON payload with the name of the topic as a property. I have a subsequent step to create the topic and subscription but it fails:
[image]

with the message '

> Service Bus messaging entity 'Topic1' or namespace '.servicebus.windows.net' not found.

I'm confused: of course the topic wasn't found - i want to create it ! 'Topic1' btw is the property that's being passed in the http request which is being correctly evaluated. So what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The action is "Create a topic **subscription**", not "Create a topic". There doesn't appear to be an action for creating a topic, and creating a subscription to a topic assumes the topic exists. While I've never used it this way, topic subscriptions can be ephemeral and relate to one particular instance of a business process, to be destroyed when this is completed - but topics themselves are intended to be longer-lived and part of your application architecture, not ephemeral objects. So this seems logical. You might consider using the Azure management REST API from the logic app using the HTTP action, otherwise create the topic through the portal or Azure cli.