# Dynamic service bus topic subscriptions

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-logic-apps

This question follows on a little from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67485730/create-a-azure-service-bus-topic-and-subscription-through-logic-app/67486079#67486079) - i've a requirement to architect an Azure based document sender app with the following requirements:

1. The user can configure multiple endpoints of different types through a web interface (http, file, email) which would send documents to those respective endpoint types (i.e. for http, a webapi endpoint, for file simply copying it to a folder location). Each endpoint will be given a name.
2. Each endpoint has to act as a queue - messages (documents) sent to that endpoint need to be processed in order. Messages need to be processed one at a time.
3. A message that is 'stuck' for one endpoint (i.e. because the http endpoint its sending to is down) shouldn't block the processing of messages on other endpoints.
4. Endpoints can be deleted.
5. The details of an endpoint are stored in a SQL database.

Naturally using an azure service bus queue would facilitate this and i've got some code which creates a topic and subscription through the SB REST Api. The problem arises with the dynamic nature of the endpoints - i can have each endpoint represented as a topic but how can i have a handler for each topic which is created dynamically with a name specified by the user ? Specifically, i can't create a function trigger for a service bus topic because that relies on knowing what the topic name is up front. I thought of having a logic app that contains a trigger handler for each topic (and which calls an azure function) but that also requires knowledge of the topic name. The alternative would be to just have one topic and have multiple filters but would that fulfil the requirements outlined above and seems to not as nice as having multiple topics (not to mention even with filters queries they're essentially based on fixed values ?). So what design would meet these requirements ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I'm not sure if you need to use the Topic-Subscription pattern here, why not using queues directly? Nonetheless, in both cases, we have to face a dynamic queue/subscription name problem.

1. Use Event Grid if you can afford Service Bus in a premium plan. Event in general for all messages, so you can trigger your function/logicApp based on that, and then pull proper message. Read doc linked below:

[image]

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-to-event-grid-integration-example
- https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/blob/master/samples/DotNet/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/ServiceBusEventGridIntegrationV2/FunctionApp1/ReceiveMessagesOnEvent.cs

2. If your queue/subscription is dynamically created do the same with the consumer. If a user creates a new endpoint, created a new queue/subscription and new logic app/Function. Use terraform or ARM template. You can try doing it from LogicApp if you want, but there is really many different ways how to do it, just pick one that suit's you.

[image]

Comment: Thanks but the tricky bit (which you don't address) is how to _programatically_  create and deploy a function that can listen on a given topic / subscription. I can have a WebApi endpoint that can create a topic and subscription but then it needs to create a resource that will do the listening. This bit cannot be done through ARM templates or CLI commands - in needs to be done through code.

Comment: It can be programmatically, after defining a logic app that creates a new consumer function, what is stopping you from calling it from your endpoint (using HTTP), after you create a topic and subscription?

Comment: Well the 'defining a logic app that creates a new consumer function'  needs to be done through code - but see my answer, i've found a post which does something similar to what i need.

Comment: "This bit cannot be done through ARM templates or CLI commands" The solution you provided is doing nothing more than using ARM and API to deploy it. 

"You can try doing it from LogicApp if you want, but there are really many different ways how to do it, just pick one that suit's you." Maybe I wasn't clean enough with this, sorry. I meant to use ARM templates in any way that suits you, in the end, it always uses ARM API.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this post [Managing a lot of azure service bus subscriptions](https://medium.com/cutting-code/managing-a-lot-of-azure-service-bus-topics-and-subscribers-ee16daaff760) which does something not dissimilar to what i need by deploying a logic app ARM template for a service bus topic subscription through code.
Alternatively i could have a timer function which simply polls each topic for messages and processes them - this might be the simpler way to go.

Comment: This is a pretty good article but doesn't address the cost problem with a solution involving logic-app as a consumer. The service-bus trigger is a pull-trigger, which means it will check for messages for a configured amount of time. Each 'check' is count as an action. If you want to do it every second - 60*60*24*30=2592000 actions per month for one logicapp which can cost you a lot of money.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/logic-apps/